# How to avoid truncation of text with UITableViewCellStyleValue2

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, truncate

I use this code to make my `UITableViewCell`s

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

If you're unfamiliar with UITableViewCellStyleValue2, the main text is shown, and then the detail text is shown after it, generally in a different color. However, when I do this, my main text is truncated, if it is longer than a short word. I want to force it to not truncate the main text and show the entire main text, and then the detail text after it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to subclass UITableViewCell.  You will need to override the `layoutSubviews` method to adjust the text label frames as needed.  I'm not sure if you will be able to do this using the standard `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` properties -- you might have to create your own text labels instead of using those properties.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am a beginner, but would you be able to provide a code example for this? I don't really understand how to adjust the bounds of the text labels.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you want, but you can make the text in the main label re-size as it gets longer. Set the `minimumFontSize` property on the `UILabel` for the main text. That way if the text is too long, it will shrink the font until the minimum size before truncating it. If you need something more complicated, you'll probably have to make your own `uiTableViewCell` subclass and lay out your own labels with text sizes.

Comment: `minimumFontSize` already defaults to 0. You also have to set `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` to enable shrinking. The cell is vertically centered, so setting `baselineAdjustment` to `UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters` is a good idea, too.